# unshare then overlay mount fails in WSL

Tags: 20.04, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, overlayfs

I Cannot overlay mount after creating an mount namespace with unshare

```
$ unshare -rm
# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/bin,upperdir=/overlay/upper/bin,workdir=/overlay/work/bin/ /overlay/merged/bin/
mount: /overlay/merged/bin: permission denied.
```

Also tried

```
$ unshare -rmpf --mount-proc
# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/bin,upperdir=/overlay/upper/bin,workdir=/overlay/work/bin/ /overlay/merged/bin/
mount: /overlay/merged/bin: permission denied.
```

Is this a limitation of wsl or because I'm not really root or am I missing something?

bind mount works

```
# mount --bind /bin /overlay/merged/bin/
# grep bin /proc/self/mountinfo
127 126 0:19 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,relatime - binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw
137 106 8:16 /bin /overlay/merged/bin rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sdb rw,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

I have write permission on upper and work and all directories are on the same filesystem

```
find /overlay/{upper,work} -name bin -ls
    38672      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 badger   badger       4096 Nov  3 17:05 /home/badger/overlay/upper/bin
    38631      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 badger   badger       4096 Nov  4 23:08 /home/badger/overlay/work/bin
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the upper and work directories? Are both on the same filesystem?

Comment: @danzel Yes I have write permissions on upper and work and all directories are on the same filesystem. I have edited my post to clarify